# estou tentando escrever um programa que faz um documento automaticamente com as informações passadas

Tags: script, texto

Estou tentado fazer o script mas eu não sei como estruturar e criar o arquivo pdf, juntando todas as informações passadas via raw_input():

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
import fileinput

enderecamento = raw_input("Digitar Endereçamento Aqui: ")
print("Dados Do Autor")
nome = raw_input("Digitar Nome Do Autor Aqui: ")
nacionalidade = raw_input("Nacionalidade Autor: ")
estado_civil = raw_input("Estado Civil Do Autor: ")
cargo = raw_input("Cargo do Autor: ")
cpf = raw_input("CPF do Autor: ")
residencia = raw_input("Residencia do Autor: ")
print (" ")
'Dados Dos Acusados'
print (" ")
nome2 = raw_input("Digitar Nome do Cusado Aqui: ")
nacionalidade2 = raw_input("Nacionalidade do Acusado: ")
estado_civil2 = raw_input("Estado Civil do Acusado: ")
cargo2 = raw_input(" Cargo do Acusado Aqui: ")
cpf2 = raw_input("CPF do Acusado: ")
residencia2 = raw_input("Residencia do Acusado: ")
acusacao = raw_input("Acusação: ")
fatos = raw_input("Digite os fatos: ")
```

Comment: Bem vindo. Favor melhorar sua pergunta com mais informações e qual a real finalidade, colocar nas tags a qual linguagem se refere, etc.

Comment: é para criar peças juridicas